# Spring profiles. Configuration database issue

Tags: configuration, spring-profiles

I'm trying to explore the Spring rofiles and did make choose the following resource:

https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-profiles-1

So, I repeat the code (only one other - with my database settings in the application.properties files), which is displayed in the tutorial:

application.properties:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
spring.application.name=profiles
app.message=This is message ${spring.application.name}
```

application-dev.properties:

```
app.message=This is message ${spring.application.name} for dev profile

#Database settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/developerparse?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.datasource.tomcat.connection-properties=useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf-8;
spring.datasource.sql-script-encoding=UTF-8
```

Configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
@SuppressWarnings("unused")

public class DBConfiguration {

    private String driverClassname;
    private String url;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @Profile("dev")
    @Bean
    public String devDatabaseConnection(){
        String DBConnection = "DB connection for DEV H2";
        System.out.println(DBConnection);
        System.out.println(driverClassname);
        System.out.println(url);
        return DBConnection;
    }
}
```

---

**So, the configuration does not work as expected in the tutorial** - when I launch the project, the following messages appear in the logs:

- .......
- .......
- **DB connection for DEV H2**
- **null**
- **null**

But expects (in tutorial) that in logs I gets the ** url ** and ** driver-class-name **:

[image]

What did I miss?

Comment: Resolved. Author missed getters and setters for **private** variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create standard getters and setters for the variables